# How to repaint canvas in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, custom-painting

Is there a way to simply reload or repaint canvas in Flutter app?

Something like `setState((){})` in stateful widgets.

Comment: yes, `CustomPainter` has `repaint` parameter in it's constructor